# Large(ish) Mysql Update query

Tags: php, mysql, csv, rdbms

I have a slightly large MySql Update query that I'd like to run on a table in my database.

The table has 10 columns, but the relevant ones are the following:

Product_Name, varchar(255), Nullable
Product_Category, varchar(255), Nullable
Product_Tags, varchar(255), Nullable

Example:

```
|  Product_Name   | Product_Category |   Product_Tags  |
|      prod1      |       cath       |    prod1 cath   |
|      prod2      |       cate       |    prod2 cate   |
|      prod3      |       catk       |    prod3 catk   |
```

I would like to `UPDATE`  the `Product_Tags` column with a concatenation of the values from `Product_Name` and `Product_Category` `WHERE` values from the string / varchar to be inserted are found in the `Product_Name` column, as illustrated above. I already have the combinations in .csv format, if that would be simpler.

What would be the correct MySql syntax for this query?

Comment: You should not do it like this. Instead add a `tags` table and a table linking the products to the tags. That will make searching a lot easier in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to update all rows of the table? If so, do this query:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `Product_Tags` = CONCATENATE(`Product_Name`, ' ', `Product_category`)
```

(But I'm not sure what you want to achieve with `Product_Tags` column.)

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked perfectly.

The Product_Tags column is to be used later for a search query, and tags are going to be added. I just wanted the initial name and category in that field at this point.

FYI, the syntax I used was:

UPDATE `Product_Data` SET `Product_Tags` = CONCAT(`Product_Name`, ' ', `Product_Catagory`)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like:

```
UPDATE Product_Tags SET Product_Tags = CONCAT_WS(" ", Product_Name, Product_Category);
```

I'm not sure I understand the `WHERE` portion of the question though. Could you give a little more detail about how you're deciding which rows this should affect?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

It would be good to see what you have so far, in essence you will need to use
UPDATE table_name
SET 'Product_Tags' = ....

I would recommend reading the tutorial above though as if you need to make any changes or write new queries it would be good to have the knowledge yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll definitely give it a read to get a bit of a firmer grasp on MySql.